# Using Select Statement in MySQL Function Call

Tags: mysql, stored-functions, sql

In the following MySQL stored function call, instead of having to manually type in the lat long coordinates, I'd like to select a polygon from another table to be tested. I'm having problems getting the syntax right.

```
SELECT IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(
POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , POLYFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON((43.40930419213147, -72.5537109375
43.40884544242924, -72.53695249557495
43.38754804789373, -72.5437331199646
43.378580946950244, -72.58398771286011
43.40930419213147, -72.5537109375 ))' )
)AS result, latitude, longitude
FROM sport
WHERE sport_type = 'lacrosse' AND IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(
POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , POLYFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON((43.40930419213147, -72.5537109375
43.40884544242924, -72.53695249557495
43.38754804789373, -72.5437331199646
43.378580946950244, -72.58398771286011
43.40930419213147, -72.5537109375))' )
) = 1;
```

So, I'd like to remove 
    43.40930419213147, -72.5537109375
    43.40884544242924, -72.53695249557495
    43.38754804789373, -72.5437331199646
    43.378580946950244, -72.58398771286011
    43.40930419213147, -72.5537109375

And instead, I'd like to use this select statement:

```
SELECT neighborhood_polygon FROM `neighborhood_shapes` WHERE neighborhood="XYZ neighborhood"
```

I have polygons stored in neighborhood_shapes. Its structure is as follows:

- neighborhood_index smallint(3)
- neighborhood varchar(50)
- neighborhood_polygon(geometry)

Additional Info:

The IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON is called as follows: IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(p POINT, poly POLYGON)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
... POLYFROMTEXT(
    (SELECT neighborhood_polygon 
      FROM neighborhood_shapes 
      Where neighborhood = "XYZ neighborhood") as coords)
```

Comment: Hi Tony318, Thank you for the message. I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, I got " #1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'POLYFROMTEXT' ". If you have any other ideas, pls let me know. I've tried everything that I can think of. Thanks.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, Help - I need your MySQL brilliance!

Comment: Possibly keep the Polygon part in? 

POLYFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON('+ (SELECT neighborhood_polygon FROM neighborhood_shapes WHERE neighborhood = "XYZ neighborhood") as coords + ')')

Play around with it for a bit. I'm not really sure

Comment: Hi Tony318, I'll try that. I also tried using AsText-- SELECT AsText(neighborhood_polygon) 
      FROM neighborhood_shapes 
      Where neighborhood = "XYZ neighborhood" but no luck.

Comment: Aside from that i'm not really sure, i voted up your question in hopes someone else sees it and can figure it out

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate that you took the time to try to help me... It's a hard question to figure out.